# New Nav - Selecting "# bounties" shows as "Need answers" - Whats the difference?

Tags: bug, new-nav

Checking out the new nav today, and it appears as if "Need answers" and "# bounties" link to the same address. Examining the markup, I discover the following (which remains the same when visiting the mentioned tabs)...

```
<a href="/?tab=new&amp;tagFilter=all" title="Recently active or interesting questions">new</a>
<a href="/?tab=popular&amp;tagFilter=all" title="Questions worth reading">popular</a>
<a class="youarehere" href="/?tagFilter=all" title="Questions that need answers">need answers</a>
<a id="tab-bounties" href="/?tagFilter=all" title="384 questions with bounty">384 bounties</a>
```

This makes me believe there is no difference between these. Also, I am not seeing a query parameter of `?tab=` for "# bounties" when visiting other tabs.

Furthermore, clicking "# bounties" does not apply the class of `.youarehere`. Is this a dedicated tab? The id of `tab-bounties` leads me to believe this is the intention.

Visually, there is no difference when visiting "Need answers" and "# bounties" - **including the returned result of questions**. Is this because "Need answers" defaults the secondary drop down to "show: bounties". If so, whats up with that?

[image]

---

For "Need answers" I would expect to see questions without answers.. but I see questions with bounties. Am I missing something? Is this correct?

Comment: `For "Need answers" I would expect to see questions without answers` => need answsers display questions without *accepted* answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by no means a definitive answer, but rather my own observations in support of this bug, and perhaps reasons for why it is behaving in this manner.

- If you navigate to the "need answers" tab and change the "show" filter to "all", it will remember that selection if you navigate to the "popular" tab and come back.
- As you gathered, when clicking the "# bounties" "tab", the "need answers" tab is refreshed with the "show" filter set to "bounties".
- When you click on the "need answers" tab again, thinking that you'll see something different, it remembers your "preference" for the "show" filter (which you unknowingly set when you clicked "# bounties") and therefore displays "bounties".

This behavior, while perhaps counter-intuitive, does appear to be by design.

However, I do believe that the fact that it is unexpected means that it is a bug of the design.

Comment: Nice observations! I'm still wondering why "need answers" is showing questions that have answers. Do you think it's intuitive to expect seeing all questions with zero answers?

Comment: @salniro - [Questions that "Need answer" are questions with no upvoted or accepted answers –  Sklivvz♦](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256848/152099)

Comment: makes sense when you put it like that